# How to fetch list of objects that doesn't follow has_one association?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

File:   User.rb

`has_one: bike`

File:   Bike.rb

`belongs_to: user`

This is the relationship that I have in my `Bike` and `User` models.
My DB already contains data with a bunch of bikes and users.

How can I pluck data using SQL or active record query that doesn't follow the above associations(has_one)?

So, all I want is the list of `Users` which has multiple `Bikes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find users who has more than 1 bike associated with the following query

```
User.joins(:bike).group('users.id').having('count(bikes.user_id) > 1')
```

Basically, we are searching for rows in `bikes` table which have same user_id more than once